# Reference destructing object before use

Tags: c++

I'd like to create an object using a

```
object().addSomething().addSomethingElse()
```

syntax and then use it in a part of the code, but the following code won't work:

```
class myObj {
public:
 myObj() {}
 ~myObj() { std::cout << "dtor called" << std::endl; }
 myObj& someOtherOperation() {
  return *this;   
 }
};

int main() {
    auto& elementRef = myObj().someOtherOperation();
    {
        std::cout << "some stuff that uses elementRef" << std::endl;
    }  
}
```

the destructor is called *before* the part of the code that uses the reference.

I would like to avoid an expensive object copy operation and keeping the

```
object().addSomething().addSomethingElse()
```

syntax, but it seems references don't allow for that. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Can you use C++11 move operations?

Comment: sure, C++11, 14 or whatever is an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the object independently:

```
auto o = myObj();
```

and then use it freely:

```
o.someOtherOperation().someOtherOperation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize by using move semantics when the implicit object parameter is an rvalue:

```
myObj someOtherOperation() & {
    return *this;   
}

myObj someOtherOperation() && {
    return std::move(*this);   
}
```

An example of the difference:

```
auto element = myObj().someOtherOperation(); //uses move semantics
myobj obj;
auto otherElement = obj.someOtherOperation(); //doesn't use move semantics
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a special exception that allows the lifetime of temporaries to be extended if they're bound to references, but when that binding is hidden through a function, it doesn't and cannot work. `int main()` could be defined in an entirely separate translation unit, where it wouldn't even see the body of `someOtherOperation()`.

You should only return `*this` by reference when you've got an lvalue.

```
myObj& someOtherOperation() & {
// -------------------------^--
  ...
  return *this;   
}
```

You can return by value, by moving from `*this`, when your method is called on an rvalue:

```
myObj someOtherOperation() && {
// ------------------------^^--
  someOtherOperation(); // keep implementation in other overload
  return std::move(*this);
}
```

Comment: a question: what is that ending '&' or '&&' ? I've never seen that

Comment: @Albert It's a new syntax added in C++11, and specifies that a member function can only be called on lvalues (`&`) or only on rvalues (`&&`).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a life "extension" if you return an **object** and bind it to a reference, i.e.

```
const Obj& foo = func_returning_an_instance();
```

in this case the instance is guaranteed to live as long as the reference.

If however your method is returning a **reference** no extension of the bound object is done... therefore in

```
const Obj& r = Obj().ref_retuning_method().ref_returning_method();
```

the expression will be computed correctly (i.e. the `Obj` instance will live enough for the full expression to be computed, thus allowing the reference returned by first call to be valid for a second call too), but the object will cease its life right after the reference `r` initialization and it won't be legal to use `r` after it.